Build a guide function for SVI in Pyro for supervised poisson matrix factorization using observed data
I am making a model for supervised poisson matrix factorization, the plate model is as follows:

My final goal is to get the posterior of \theta, \beta, \xi, \ni, \nu, and \gamma using SVI in pyro. So I have to write a guide function, My observed variables are X, X' (X_aux in the code), and Y.
Now I have made the code for the model and I can generate the data with expected dimensions for variables.
But I have problems with the guide function.
This is my model function:
def model(x_data, x_aux_data, y_data):

    n = 200  
    p = 50  
    k = 3  
    d = 20  
    p_aux = 10  
    
    sigma = torch.tensor(1, dtype=torch.float)  # Standard deviation for the Normal distributions
    mu = torch.tensor(0, dtype=torch.float)  # mean for the Normal distributions
    
    a = torch.tensor(2, dtype=torch.float)
    a_prime = torch.tensor(2, dtype=torch.float)
    b_prime = torch.tensor(1, dtype=torch.float)
    c = torch.tensor(2, dtype=torch.float)
    c_prime = torch.tensor(2, dtype=torch.float)
    d_prime = torch.tensor(1, dtype=torch.float)

    features_axis = pyro.plate("features_axis", p_aux, dim=-5)
    module_axis = pyro.plate("module_axis", k, dim=-4)
    sample_axis = pyro.plate("sample_axis", n, dim=-3)
    gene_axis = pyro.plate("gene_axis", p, dim=-2)
    latent_factors_axis = pyro.plate("latent_factors_axis", d, dim=-1)
    
    with gene_axis:
        ni = pyro.sample('ni', dist.Gamma(c_prime, d_prime))
    
    with latent_factors_axis, gene_axis:
        beta = pyro.sample('beta', dist.Gamma(c, ni))
    
    with sample_axis:
        xi = pyro.sample('xi', dist.Gamma(a_prime, b_prime))
    
    with latent_factors_axis, sample_axis:
        theta = pyro.sample('theta', dist.Gamma(a, xi))
    
    rate = torch.matmul(theta, beta.T)
    x_squeezed = rate.squeeze(1)
    x = pyro.sample('x', dist.Poisson(x_squeezed), obs=x_data)
        
    with latent_factors_axis, module_axis:
        nu = pyro.sample('nu', dist.Normal(mu, sigma))
    
    with features_axis, module_axis:
        gamma = pyro.sample('gamma', dist.Normal(mu, sigma))
    
    with sample_axis, features_axis:
        x_aux = pyro.sample('x_aux', dist.Normal(mu, sigma), obs=x_aux_data)
        # x_aux = pyro.sample('x_aux', dist.Normal(mu, sigma))
    
    bern_term1 = torch.matmul(theta.squeeze(1), nu.squeeze(1, 2).T)
    bern_term2 = torch.matmul(x_aux.squeeze(1, 3, 4).T, gamma.squeeze(2, 3, 4))
    ben_arg = bern_term1 + bern_term2
    module_probs = torch.sigmoid(ben_arg)
    y = pyro.sample('y', dist.Bernoulli(probs=module_probs), obs=y_data)
    # y = pyro.sample('y', dist.Bernoulli(probs=module_probs))
    return x, x_aux, y

and this is my guide function:
def guide(x_data, x_aux_data, y_data):
    n = 200  
    p = 50  
    k = 3  
    d = 20  
    p_aux = 10  
    
    # Define variational parameters for ni
    c_prime_q = pyro.param('c_prime_q', torch.ones(p, dtype=torch.float), constraint=dist.constraints.positive)
    d_prime_q = pyro.param('d_prime_q', torch.ones(p, dtype=torch.float), constraint=dist.constraints.positive)
    ni = pyro.sample('ni', dist.Gamma(c_prime_q, d_prime_q))
    
    # Define variational parameters for beta
    c_q = pyro.param('c_q', torch.ones(d, p, dtype=torch.float), constraint=dist.constraints.positive)
    beta = pyro.sample('beta', dist.Gamma(c_q, ni))
    
    # Define variational parameters for xi
    a_prime_q = pyro.param('a_prime_q', torch.ones(n, dtype=torch.float), constraint=dist.constraints.positive)
    b_prime_q = pyro.param('b_prime_q', torch.ones(n, dtype=torch.float), constraint=dist.constraints.positive)
    xi = pyro.sample('xi', dist.Gamma(a_prime_q, b_prime_q))
    
    # Define variational parameters for theta
    a_q = pyro.param('a_q', torch.ones(d, n, dtype=torch.float), constraint=dist.constraints.positive)
    theta = pyro.sample('theta', dist.Gamma(a_q, xi))
    
    # Define variational parameters for nu
    nu_mu = pyro.param('nu_mu', torch.zeros(d, k, dtype=torch.float))
    nu_scale = pyro.param('nu_scale', torch.ones(d, k, dtype=torch.float), constraint=dist.constraints.positive)
    nu = pyro.sample('nu', dist.Normal(nu_mu, nu_scale))
    
    # Define variational parameters for gamma
    gamma_mu = pyro.param('gamma_mu', torch.zeros(p_aux, k, dtype=torch.float))
    gamma_scale = pyro.param('gamma_scale', torch.ones(p_aux, k, dtype=torch.float),
                             constraint=dist.constraints.positive)
    gamma = pyro.sample('gamma', dist.Normal(gamma_mu, gamma_scale))

I generate data using a the same model, and I use the following code to use SVI:
optimizer = pyro.optim.Adam({"lr": 0.01})

# Setup the inference algorithm
svi = pyro.infer.SVI(model=model,
                     guide=guide,
                     optim=optimizer,
                     loss=pyro.infer.Trace_ELBO())

# Number of iterations
num_iterations = 1000


# Run inference
for i in range(num_iterations):
    loss = svi.step(x_data, x_aux_data, y_data)
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print(f"Iteration {i} : Loss {loss}")

But I get the following error:
ValueError: Shape mismatch inside plate('latent_factors_axis') at site beta dim -1, 20 vs 50
(pyro version: 1.9.0, python: 3.10)
I suspect the guide model is incomplete, because in the model I manipulate the dimensions of matrices so that I can multiply them, but I am not sure how I should reflect them in the guide function.
I would appreciate if anybody know how can I tackle this problem.
I tried to remove the supervised part, but I still have problems.
